# How to estimate Rails app development cost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, estimation

I have an application I would like built. For the most part, I know what I want. And, I have good sketches of how it should work and look.

I would like to understand how to estimate the cost to implement an application. I would like to do this prior to approaching developers so that I can make sure I can afford to fund the development myself and not waste anyone's time.

I can imagine that this is *not* an easy question to answer, and perhaps one that can't be answered here at all.  However, I'm hoping there are some ballpark figures and methods to approximate cost.

Also, If anyone has any suggested steps to going from idea to implementation, I'd love to hear them. Thanks!

*Clarification: I'm not looking for an answer with a dollar amount. I'm looking for guidance on how to come up with a (very rough) figure. Ultimately, I'll be using this figure to determine whether or not I can comfortably fund development personally. Again, this question may be flawed, but I can't help but think that someone might have a savvy answer. Perhaps a figure of cost/time based on a project of their own or good advice otherwise. Just don't tell me it'll cost a million, because Robert already has. :)*

Comment: Whenever people ask me how much something is going to cost without telling me what the 'something' is, I always reply with "1 million dollars."

Comment: Good thing I asked "how to" and not "how much". And, isn't "1 million dollars" a little high for an unknown 'something'? Maybe you should start with "I don't know". :)

Comment: The last thing I want to say to a customer is "I don't know." How am I supposed to get a million dollars if I don't know how to do it?

Comment: I don't know who your customers are, or whether or not you have a one-way door, but I'd rather tell mine "I don't know" than "1 million dollars". :)

Comment: I think $1 million is fair compensation for exercising psychic abilities to give you what you want without you having to say what it is that you want. Actually, I think $10 million is a fairer figure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, if the project is in the middle ground where you may or may not be able to fund it personally, I'd say err on the side of caution. Too often, a project that should be able to be completed in a certain amount of time drags on. That can be the result of a mistaken estimate or because of opportunities that open up in the project that expand the scope. The worst thing I've seen happen to a promising project is that it runs out of funding just as it start to build steam.

Comment: Solid point and good advice. This is why I'd like to understand some of the quantities used in estimating development costs. (e.g. cost/hour, cost/month) I figure that with those, I can use rough time estimates to come up with a ballpark implementation cost. This number would be helpful in me determining whether or not this is a venture I can fund alone. ($20K vs $100K) Thanks Yehuda!

Answer (score 2):

You say you have good sketches of how it should work and look. Get that together with some text describing EVERYTHING about the app. Now you can post that for bids on Elance and ODesk or wherever (those are just two that come to mind). The more detail you have, the better it is.

Answer (score 1):

Get some quotes is the only way to know really.

It also depends on what you are **getting** as a product ... the source? it hosted?

Some web-firms that will also host your app have in-house CMS and work systems to get things done cheaper/faster. This doesn't mean they will pass the cost back however.

Cheapest, also isn't best. You need to **set a budget and get the most for it**.